# Flebox one item center, second end

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 items with the following structure:

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">

        <div class="logo">
            Center
        </div>

        <div class="scroll">
            <a href="#about-us">
                End
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I need `Center` to be centered horizontally & vertically BUT `End` should be on bottom of page.
Is it possible to do this with Flex? I'm using Bootstrap 4.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byucwhzg/1/)

Comment: Should `End` be centered as well?  The problem is that the your root container is; A not the height of the page, and B your flex container isn't set to grow/fill vertically.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Yes but only horizontally.

Comment: take the time to read the accepted answer and you will find your use case there